# Most adequate writing point of view in self-answered questions

Tags: discussion, self-answer, answer-quality

Which is the most adequate writing point of view to self-answer a question?

**1. First person.** Taking into account that the person who asks and answers are the same. Something like:

> I found a solution to **my** problem. That's the following...

**2. Impersonal / third person.** Like if the person who asks and answers would not be the same. Something like:

> The solution to this problem is...

**3. Another one?**

Comment: Funny about those examples, neither is ever needed--don't announce that you're going to say something, just say it. Similarly just saying the minimal amount, one seldom needs to refer to oneself: running with that input gives output x. Use "I" when you are actually relevant: if one is giving an impression one can say, I suspect, since one's uncertainty is essential, though still one could just say, maybe. Much "I think" is unnecessary or misleading though: if you think it is so, don't announce it, just say it; and often it means I don't think x is so, I'm not sure--so say I'm not sure.

Comment: "Omit needless words."--Strunk & White

Comment: For a self-Q&A I'd go with the following. **Question**: *pretend* you don't know the answer. Ask the question in a natural way that fits that. So, something like "I have a problem here are details A, B, and C. I want to do X but I get Y". Just like a normal question would be. **Answer**: *pretend* you're answering the question from a different user. Write in neutral tone. So it would look something like "the reason is related to B - the result is different for <some reason>. In order to get X, don't use B but use D". Something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When self-answering I would use the first person for both question and answer because it is my question and I am supplying my answer to it.

That does not mean that others cannot improve my question and answer, but when they do, I would prefer that they remain in the first person, at least until such time that question and answer are improved to the point where they are not recognizable as being content that I contributed.